Weather Data with F1 Driver Performance in Python
I am working on a data science project to analyze F1 driver performance based on weather conditions. I am using a dataset from kaggle that contains detailed information about F1 races, such as driver positions, qualifying and race results, and other relevant parameters such as race dates and locations.
I am trying to integrate weather data using the OpenWeatherMap API to understand the impact of weather conditions on driver performance.
Here is what I have already done:
I downloaded the dataset from Kaggle and loaded the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame.
I cleaned the data to ensure it was ready for analysis.
I configured the OpenWeatherMap API to fetch real-time weather information (such as temperature) for each race location.
The code to retrieve the weather data looks like this:
import requests

city = 'Sakhir'  # Example race circuit
api_key = 'your_actual_api_key'  # Replace with your valid API key

url = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={api_key}&units=metric"
response = requests.get(url)
weather_data = response.json()

# Extract weather information
temperature = weather_data['main']['temp']
weather_conditions = weather_data['weather'][0]['description']
print(f"Temperature at {city}: {temperature}°C")
print(f"Weather conditions: {weather_conditions}")

I already have weather data in a CSV file (weather_data.csv), and I want to merge it with the F1 dataset. However, I'm not sure how to properly integrate the two datasets and analyze the relationship between weather conditions and driver performance.
Here’s the structure of the weather data:
The columns in weather_data.csv are:
raceId, driverId, constructorId, grid, position, positionOrder, points, laps, year, round, name, date, time_race, fp1_date, fp1_time, fp2_date, fp2_time, fp3_date, fp3_time, quali_date, quali_time, sprint_date, sprint_time, driverRef, number_driver, code, forename, surname, dob, nationality, constructorRef, name_constructor, nationality_constructor, circuitRef, name_circuit, location, country, status, points_standings, position_standings.

I need to match the weather data (which includes weather parameters like temperature, humidity, and conditions) with the race data, based on raceId and date.
What I’ve done so far:
I have successfully obtained weather data from OpenWeatherMap API.
I now have the weather data saved in weather_data.csv.
I want to combine this data with the F1 race data to analyze the relationship between weather and driver performance.
Questions:
How can I merge the weather_data.csv with the F1 race dataset based on the race date and location (using raceId and date)?
What statistical or visual methods can I use to analyze the impact of weather conditions (such as temperature, precipitation, and humidity) on F1 driver performance (like race positions, points, and laps)?
Should I preprocess the weather data (for example, convert date formats) before merging it with the race data?
Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
What I tried :
import pandas as pd

# Charger les datasets
race_data = pd.read_csv('f1_race_data.csv')  # Vos données F1
weather_data = pd.read_csv('weather_data.csv')  # Vos données météo

# Convertir les formats de date
race_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(race_data['date'])
weather_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(weather_data['date'])

# Fusionner les deux datasets sur raceId et la date
merged_data = pd.merge(race_data, weather_data, on=['raceId', 'date'], how='inner')

